# Framework URL rewriting

Tags: php, phalcon

When I load `http://localhost/test`, I get redirected to `http://localhost/public/?_url=/test`

Here is my Apache config. I also tested to make sure rewrite_module is loaded.

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/myapp/"

<Directory "/var/www/myapp/">
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I created the project using Phalcon Dev Tools `phalcon project myapp`. Here are the two .htaccess files it created automatically.

```
cat /var/www/myapp/.htaccess 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
    RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

cat /var/www/myapp/public/.htaccess 
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Using Phalcon 1.2.6, Apache/2.2.24

Comment: "Getting this URL"‽ Where? How? When?

Comment: @decese http://localhost/myapp/test will get converted into http://localhost/myapp/public?_url=/test

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your apache config should be something like

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/myapp/public/"

<Directory "/var/www/myapp/public/">
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Secondly there should be a .htaccess file in your public directory like this one :-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
    RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I hope this resolves this issue.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the .htaccess files. I understand your approach to point to public folder, but the project created by Phalcon dev tools included two .htaccess files